# Create dataframe reading json file using json schema file outside the code

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

What is the best way to create a dataframe for a json file using a separate json schema file in **pyspark**?.

Sample json file

```
{"ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME":"Romania","DEST_COUNTRY_NAME":"United States","count":1}
{"ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME":"Ireland","DEST_COUNTRY_NAME":"United States","count":264}
{"ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME":"India","DEST_COUNTRY_NAME":"United States","count":69}
{"ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME":"United States","DEST_COUNTRY_NAME":"Egypt","count":24}
```

Code to read this file

```
df_json = spark.read.format("json")\
    .option("mode", "FAILFAST")\
    .option("inferschema", "true")\
    .load("C:\\pyspark\\data\\2010-summary.json")
```

If I don't want to use the "inferschema" option and want to use a json schema file instead, may I know how to do that?

json schema file

```
{"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {"ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME": {"type": "string"},
                 "DEST_COUNTRY_NAME": {"type": "string"},
                 "count": {"type": "integer"}
                },
  "required": ["ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME","DEST_COUNTRY_NAME","count"]
}
```

Comment: Your question could do with some clarification. Are you able to edit what you've already posted provide a code example of what you mean. Perhaps an example of a the schema being directly typed into the code itself.

Comment: You can parse you schema file and create the appropriate `StructType` schema and then  pass it to your `spark.read` call. Here's an example for scala. But the same should be doable in pyspark. https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-json-with-schema/

Comment: I saw that example before posting. In my case I would like to keep the schema out of the code, reason being, if there are any future schema changes, I don't want to be changing the actual code, I can just update the schema file. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### option1:

I assumed your columns are all nullable,

```
from spark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType


yourSchema = StructType([ StructField("ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME", StringType(), True),
                          StructField("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME", StringType(), True),
                          StructField("count", IntegerType(), True),])
```

#### option2:

simple read your file like so..

```
df_json = spark.read.json("C:\\pyspark\\data\\2010-summary.json")
df_jsonSchema = df_json.schema

print(type(df_jsonSchema))
[each for each in zipsDFSchema]
```

from the results, you can then build your schema just like in option1.